# scss:compact (плагин для sublime/atom)

Tags: sublime-text-3, atom

На работе есть свой стиль написания и нужно писать scss как (:compact), а не в столбик. Хотел узнать может кто-то знает какой-то плагин, что бы нажать сочетание клавиш и он бы перестроил код из столбика в (:compact) и наоборот в самом редакторе кода?

[image: Пример]

Comment: можешь использовать минификаторы, в интернете их полно

Comment: Вам нужно весь код в одну строчку уместить для оптимизации? [`sass --watch a.scss:a.css --style compressed`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8980421/5951529). Системы сборки вроде [**Grunt**](http://frontender.info/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/) это делают. Также данную задачу выполняют программы, называющиеся Minifier, в [**данном**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28868117/5951529) ответе содержится их обзор для Sublime Text. // Если Вы другое имели в виду под «в ряд», поясните, желательно, на конкретных примерах. Спасибо.

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: Есть плагин для Sb3: "HTML,CSS,JS Prettify", и еще один: "CSS Format"

Comment: CSS Format нужен такой же только для Sass(Scss)

Comment: to user190134 Хотя, попробовал он работает на scss тоже, спасибо выручил